# Null Pointer error RSS feed

Tags: android, rss, android-asynctask, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to build a basic RSS Feed. I have no errors showing up in code however when I run the application it crashes with the following error:

**FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()**

This is my MainActivity.java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

List<String> headlines;
List<String>links;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //initialize variables
    headlines = new ArrayList<String>();
    links = new ArrayList<String>();

    new PostTask().execute();

    //binding data to list
    ArrayAdapter <String>adapter=  new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}

private InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
    try{
        return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    }catch(IOException e){
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(links.get(position));
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//ASYNCH CLASS
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        try{
            //link to data source
            URL url = new URL("http://feeds.pcworld.com/pcworld/latestnews");

            //Set up parser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            //get XML from input stream
            xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

            //Keep track of which tag inside of XML
            boolean insideItem = false;

            //Loop through the XML file and extract data required
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
            while(eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT){
                if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                    insideItem = true;
                }else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
                    if(insideItem){
                        //Get title
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText());
                    }
                }else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
                    if(insideItem){
                        //Get link
                        links.add(xpp.nextText());
                    }
                }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem = false;
            }
            eventType = xpp.next();//move to next element
        }
    }catch(MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        return null;
    }

    public void onPostExecute(URL url) {

    }

}
```

}

Can anyone point me to where I am going wrong? Many thanks!

LOG CAT ERRORS:

```
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at com.example.simplerss.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at com.example.simplerss.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-11 17:27:50.061: E/AndroidRuntime(7746):     ... 4 more
```

Comment: why you have added  `new PostTask().onPostExecute(url);` in `doInBackground` ?

Comment: You should always post all of your LogCat errors when your app crashes.

Comment: That was a typo overlooked by me. I removed it ran again but still same result of NPE and app crashing.

Comment: @Sam posting Log cat errors now

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.example.simplerss.MainActivity$PostTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:89)` What is line 89?

Comment: `if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item"))`

Comment: @Javacadabra : make sure you are getting xml from server see in log

Comment: Well, either `xpp` is null or `getName()` returns null... Your debugger can help you determine which one. But your if-else block in your while-loop has a few logic errors, for instance you will never enter the last `else if`. Walk through `xpp`'s results step by step to see what data you are actually getting.

Comment: @sam Looking at the debugger I can see that xpp.getName() does not seem to be returning anything. I suppose there must be a problem with the way I'm parsing as you said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `xpp.getClass()` returns null when `xpp` references the text inside a set of tags. If you look at the example in [XmlPullParser's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html):

```
 while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
  if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
      System.out.println("Start document");
  } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
      System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
  } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
      System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
  } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
      System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
  }
  eventType = xpp.next();
 }
```

Notice that the focus is on the `eventType`. If you only want to grab `"title"` and 
`"link"` tags, add these checks inside the section for `START_TAG`:

```
else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
    if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")){
        //Get title
    }else if(xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")){
        //Get link
    }
}
```

Comment: When the doInBackground() method completes is there something I have to pass to onPostExecute()? Because Now I am reading the XML however it is not displaying.

Comment: I see, after the code exits your loop you should call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` _or_ use `adapter.add(xpp.nextText());` instead of `headlines.add();`

Comment: `notifyingDataSetChanged()` within the onPostExecute() method did the trick. Thank you for your help.